# What is the probability that 4 people are born in different month?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I will give you my solution of the problem, the answer I found is really surprising (about 0.0238) and this is why I come here to ask for the real answer or correction.

**Be carefull, the following answer is probably false:**

First of all, I assign to each people a number between 1-4 such that their birthmonths are in increasing order. I define the following events:

- $G_{i,j}$ = the $i^{th}$ person is born in the $j^{th}$ month.

The event corresponding to "4 people are born in different month" is given by:

- A = $\bigcup\limits_{1\leq j<k<l<n\leq 12} (G_{1,j}\cap G_{2,k}\cap G_{3,l}\cap G_{4,n})$

Since we can assume that the birthmonths are independant, we have:

- $P(G_{1,j}\cap G_{2,k}\cap G_{3,l}\cap G_{4,n})$=$P(G_{1,j})P(G_{2,k})P(G_{3,l})P(G_{4,l})$=$\frac{1}{12^4}$

for all $1\leq j,k,l,n\leq 12$.

Using sigma additivity and some combinatorics, we have:

- P(A) = $\sum\limits_{1\leq j<k<l<n\leq 12}\frac{1}{12^4}=\frac{{12 \choose 4}}{12^4}$=0.0238...

Comment: Assuming the four people are distinct (and since the months are obviously distinct), shouldn't it be $12P4$ and not $12C4$, in the end? Alice being born in janurary is not the same as alice being born in feb.

Comment: It should be $(12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9)/12^4\approx 0.5729$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is wrong is that it calculates the probability that people 1-4 are born in different months *in that order*. To get the total probability of them being born in different months, you have to count all possible orders, so you need to multiply by $4!$.